# Coffeescript: invoking function with space before parens

Tags: function, coffeescript, parentheses

When I invoke a function with a space before the parens, it gives an error saying unepected ,

```
sum = (a, b) ->
  a+b
console.log (sum (1, 2))
```

error: unexpected ,
console.log (sum (1, 2))

it points to the comma between 1 and 2

Why the odd behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CoffeeScript you can write function calls in two ways:

```
foo(bar) # with parens
foo bar  # without parens
```

Since you have a space between `sum` and `(1, 2)`, then you are making a unparenthesized functional call of `sum` passing `(1, 2)` as the first parameter, equivalent to this:

```
bar = (1, 2)
sum bar
```

The problem is that `(1, 2)` is not a valid CoffeeScript expression. To pass two parameters, you have to use either of:

```
sum(1, 2)
sum 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses serve various purposes in CoffeeScript; the purposes that are relevant here are:

1. Grouping within expressions.
2. Function calls.

The parentheses for functions calls are often optional so you can say this:

```
console.log 6, 11
```

and everything's fine. The problem occurs when there is some ambiguity between grouping parentheses and function calling parentheses. Consider this:

```
f = (n) -> 2*n
f (1 + 2) + 3
```

What is the result? If the parentheses are for grouping then we have:

```
x = (1 + 2) + 3 #  6
f x             # 12
```

but if the parentheses indicate a function call then we have:

```
x = 1 + 2 # 3
y = f x   # 6
y + 3     # 9
```

So there is some ambiguity about what the parentheses mean and the result of the expression depends on how that ambiguity is resolved. If there is a space between the function name and the opening parentheses:

```
f (1 + 2) + 3
```

then CoffeeScript uses the parentheses for grouping and, filling in the optional parentheses, the function call is seen like this:

```
x = (1 + 2) + 3
f(x)
```

However, if there isn't any space then it is seen as:

```
x = (1 + 2)
f(x) + 3
```

So if there is a space before the opening parentheses then CoffeeScript assumes that it should fill in the implied parentheses for the function call; if there isn't a space then the parentheses are seen as explicit rather than implied.

Now we can look at your specific case:

```
console.log (sum (1, 2))
```

The spaces after `log` and `sum` indicate that the parentheses are used for grouping and `(1, 2)` isn't a valid CoffeeScript expression.

Rule of thumb: if you want (or need) to use parentheses to indicate a function call then don't put any space between the function name and the opening parenthesis.