# coffeescript throw Error("ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: unexpected , in function

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

I have written this function in coffeescript:

```
doCalculate = (old, new) ->
  difference = roundNumber (old - new, 5)
```

but when compiled generates the error:

```
throw Error("ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: unexpected ,
```

If I remove the `, 5` part I get no error any more.

I can't figure what's wrong with a comma.

The function `roundNumber` is defined as follows, in the same file:

```
 roundNumber = (rnum, rlength = 6) ->
   pow = Math.pow( 10, rlength )
   newnumber = Math.round ( rnum * pow ) / pow
   parseFloat(newnumber)
```

Comment: do `roundNumber(entry - exit, 5)`

Comment: The error happens regardless I use the default value in rlength or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coffeescript: invoking function with space before parens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985675/coffeescript-invoking-function-with-space-before-parens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ahhhh I figured it out. coffeescript requires that there is no space between the function name and the open parenthesis.

it even works with no parentheses at all.

but not if there's a space between the function name and the (.

this works:

```
difference = roundNumber old - new, 5
```

Thanks :)